# rqt plugin with custom icon in Ubuntu sidebar (Unity Launcher)

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
is there a way to set a custom icon for a rqt plugin, that is then shown in the Ubuntu sidebar (Unity Launcher)? If you have several rqt plugins open, a custom icon would help to switch between the rqt windows.

I want basically replace the ROS icon in  the image below:

[image: image description]

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211182/rqt-plugin-with-custom-icon-in-ubuntu-sidebar-(unity-launcher)/) by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-06-13**:
+1. But I just wanted to reiterate that rqt allows multiple tools/plugins laid out on a single window, as a screenshot in http://wiki.ros.org/rqt?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ros_gui.png

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-13**:
Are you starting `rqt` and then select plugins from the menu or are you invoking individual plugins in standalone mode, e.g. `rqt_graph`, `rqt_plot`?

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2015-06-14**:
@Dirk Thomas, I invoke my own plugins usually in standalone mode.

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2015-06-14**:
@130s, for the case where you have multiple plugins in the same window, it would be nice to define an icon for the perspective. Is that possible? I guess not (couldn't find something about it)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-14**:
No, perspectives currently don't have an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The next release of `rqt` will use the plugin icon for the application when running in standalone mode: https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/pull/54

If you have defined an icon for your plugin that will address your use case.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2015-06-14**:
cool, thanks.
Is it possible to do something similar for perspectives?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-14**:
Plugins already have an icon and they are provided with the ROS package. Perspectives are user created and don't have an icon. So that would require more effort - also from the user whenever a perspective is created. Therefore I don't think I will implement it but pull requests are always welcome.